# Google directory API Retrieve a user as a non-administrator.

Tags: google-api-php-client, google-apps-marketplace

I have a google marketplace app that has a service account with the following permissions:
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email,https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.group.readonly,https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.orgunit.readonly,https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user.readonly

When a non-admin user authenticates into the app, the app needs to see that user's orgUnitPath in order to know where to place that user.

Specifying viewType=domain_public when doing a $directory->users->get call doesn't return the orgUnitPath, but when I specify viewType=admin_view I get an exception that the user doesn't have authorization to access this API.

Any ideas?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The `orgUnitPath` field is not returned using the "domain_public" `viewType`, as you've found. Instead, you'll need to use the `viewType` "admin_view" (the default) and make the request as an admin. You can use the service account to impersonate an admin on the domain, as shown [here](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/delegation).

Comment: Thanks, but I'm still getting the same issue. Since this is a marketplace app the domain admin grants domain-wide authority permissions at the time of installation, right? When I look at the domain admin security panel I see that my app name has the right permissions. Is there anything else I can check?

Comment: Granting domain-wide authority allows the service account to impersonate any user. However, this request will only work if you impersonate a domain admin. Are you doing that?

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm doing it correctly. I'm using the service account name (that ends with @developer.gserviceaccount.com). And that doesn't work. I also trying setting credentials with service account name that matches an email of an admin for that domain but that didn't work either. The code is based on the /google-api-php-client/examples/service-account.php - I set the client_id, service_account_name and key_file_location to the correct params.

Comment: See this page for how to do this in PHP: https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php/guide/aaa_oauth2_service. The `Google_Auth_AssertionCredentials` object is created with the email of the service account, and the user to impersonate is set in the `sub` field.